# facebook sharing shows nullpointer exception at jsonobject graphresponse

Tags: android, json, facebook

I want to publish link if the user is logged in facebook and if not make user logged in and then publish link but it shows `NullPointerException` at jsonobject graphresponse in the publishlink() method.

Following is my code..

```
public static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
public static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";
public boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

public void ShareOnFacebook(String sharingpath)
{
    Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
        Session session = new Session.Builder(getBaseContext()).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        currentSession = session;
    }

    else if (!currentSession.isOpened()) {
        // Ask for username and password
        OpenRequest op = new Session.OpenRequest(this);

        op.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
        op.setCallback(statusCallback);

        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        permissions.add("publish_stream");
        op.setPermissions(permissions);

        Session session = new Session(this);
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        Log.d("session", "opening sesion for publish action!!");
        session.openForPublish(op);
    }
    }

private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback
{
    @Override
    public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
    {
        //we have callback here

        if (session.isOpened())
        {
            Log.d("session", "session is already opened ,we are in the callback section...going to publish link!!");
            PublishLink();
    }
} 
}

public void PublishLink()
 {

SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("shared",MODE_PRIVATE); 
String path = prefs.getString("path", "");

Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        // Check for publish permissions   

        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                    .NewPermissionsRequest(this,PERMISSIONS);
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);

        }

        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("link", path);
        Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {

            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                Log.d("graphresponse", response.toString());
                 JSONObject graphResponse =         response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                String postId = null;
                try {
                    postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d(
                        "JSON error "+ e.getMessage(), postId);
                }

                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (error != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                         getApplicationContext(),
                         error.getErrorMessage(),
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                             getApplicationContext(), 
                             postId,
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };


        Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();


 }
public boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
for (String string : subset) {
    if (!superset.contains(string)) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
}
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("data", "data coming to onactivityresult: "+data);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally figured out there was error in

```
 Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
```

so change it to

```
 Request request = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(session, path, callback);
```

hope this helps someone who have this problem.
so we donot need to create new Bundle anymore ....
we can remove create Bundle and postparams.putString lines in above code..

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the requestNewPublishPermissions() method is an asynchronous request, and when you call it, it returns immediately, but at that point, you don't have the publish permissions yet.

What you're doing is making a "publish" request, regardless of whether you have the publish permissions yet, and so the response is going to have an error rather than a GraphObject result.

If you check the response.getError(), you'll likely see a permission error (you should always check that first, before accessing anything else in the Response).

Have a look at the HelloFacebook sample on how to temporarily cache the information you want to post (while you wait for the requestNewPublishPermissions to finish), and only post when you have all the permissions necessary.

Comment: :thanx for your response....i tried it it was not error in permission it was error on request ...